# Show if $f$ is increasing then so is $f^{-1}$

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

> Show if $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is increasing then so is $f^{-1}$.

**My Attempt**
If $f$ is increasing then by definition; $$x<y \iff f(x)<f(y)$$ which implies $$f^{-1}(x)<f^{-1}(y) \iff f^{-1}(f(x))<f^{-1}(f(y))$$ which is the same as
$$f^{-1}(x)<f^{-1}(y) \iff x<y$$
And so $f^{-1}$ is increasing.
Is this proof correct??

Answer (score 1):

Your proof seems to actually assume $f^{-1}$ is increasing, and is therefore circular. Namely,
$$x < y \Longleftrightarrow f(x) < f(y)$$
only implies
$$f^{-1}(x) < f^{-1}(y) \Longleftrightarrow f^{-1}(f(x)) < f^{-1}(f(y))$$
if $f^{-1}$ is an increasing function. You kind of want to do things the other way around. First assume $f^{-1}(x) < f^{-1}(y)$ and use $f$ to get a comparison between $x$ and $y$. Repeat similarly to get the reverse implication.